# A question about how to show two polynomials are not equal

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let $f\in k[x_i,i=0,\ldots ,n]$ be a a polynomial which contains $x_0$ (i.e. polynomial like $f=x_1$ is not allowed), where $k$ is a field with characteristic $0$. We define a map
$$Q_a: k[x_i,i=0,\ldots ,n] \to k[x_i,i=1,\ldots ,n]$$
which sends $f(x_0,\ldots,x_n)$ to $f(a_1x_1+\ldots+a_n x_n, x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, where $a=(a_1,\ldots a_n)$ is a parameter.

My question is

> if $a\neq a'$, is it true that $Q_a(f)\neq Q_{a'}(f)$?

I think this should be true, but I did not find a good way to show it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counterexample:   let $f(x_0,x_1,x_2)=x_0^2+x_1^2+x_2^2$.  Let $a=(1,-1)$, and $a'=(-1,1)$.

Then $Q_a(f)=Q_{a'}(f)$.

Comment: I think just $f(x) = x_0^2$ with any $a' = -a$ works.

Comment: You're right...

Comment: Now I think this should be true for for nearby $a$ and $a'$. I asked another question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2962486/a-question-about-how-to-show-two-polynomials-are-not-equal-follow-up) :)

Answer (score 0):

Start from the Leading coefficient,(If two were equal) the coefficient of the highest power of the polynomial must be equal, then the second highest must be equal ...

As for the proof, you may consider use induction on the degree of polynomials.

Comment: I think this should be the right way. But could you try to write it more explicitly?