# A question about how to show two polynomials are not equal (follow-up)

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

This is a follow-up of my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2962430/a-question-about-how-to-show-two-polynomials-are-not-equal/2962467#2962467), but it is self-contained.

Let $f\in k[x_i,i=0,\ldots ,n]$ be a a polynomial which contains $x_0$ (i.e. polynomial like $f=x_1$ is not allowed), where $k$ is a field with characteristic $0$. We define a map
$$Q_a: k[x_i,i=0,\ldots ,n] \to k[x_i,i=1,\ldots ,n]$$
which sends $f(x_0,\ldots,x_n)$ to $f(a_1x_1+\ldots+a_n x_n, x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, where $a=(a_1,\ldots a_n)$ is a parameter.

Now my question is

> Is it true that there exists a neighborhood $U_a$ of $a$, such that for all $U_a\ni a '\neq a$,we have $Q_a(f)\neq Q_{a'}(f)$?

---

I think one way is to show for fixed $a$ there is only finitely many $a'$ with $Q_a(f)= Q_{a'}(f)$.

Comment: Is $a \in k^n$? If so, what is the topology on $k^n$ (i.e. what is the definition of a neighborhood of $a$)?

Comment: @AlexanderJ93 Yes $a\in k^n$. The best thing I expect is there are only finitely many $a'$ such that $Q_a(f)=Q_{a'}(f)$, so there would be no difference between Zariski topology and the usual topology.